# QT: cannot access private member declared in class 'QByteArray'

Tags: c++, qt, char, qbytearray, toupper

I've been trying to create a random phrase generator, which reads nouns from one text file and verbs from another text file. That all worked, but now I'm trying to write a method that capitalizes the first letter of the subject, but keep getting the errors

error: C2248: 'QByteArray::operator QNoImplicitBoolCast' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QByteArray'

see declaration of 'QByteArray::operator QNoImplicitBoolCast'

see declaration of 'QByteArray'

I'll post the code for the method (sorry if its not in proper format I'm new)

```
    void MainWindow::returnCap(QString sub){

        char *str;
        QByteArray ba;
        ba = sub.toLatin1();
        str = ba.data();
        QString firstLetter;
        firstLetter = str[0];
        QString cappedFirstLetter;
        cappedFirstLetter = firstLetter.toUpper();
        char flc; //firstLetterChar
        flc = cappedFirstLetter.toLatin1();
        str[0] = flc;
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And *where* do you get the errors? On what line?

Comment: flc = cappedFirstLetter.toLatin1();

Comment: toLatin1 returns QByteArray... you have to cast it to char* with .data or char

Comment: @ArcWalrus, you want to assign byte array to a char? Hmm...

Comment: If you're trying to make the fist letter of `sub` upper-case, why not simply do `sub[0] = toupper(sub[0])`? Also, you're passing `sub` *by value* so you're only modifying a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assigning a byte array to a single character. However you need only one character from the byte array:

```
char flc; //firstLetterChar
flc = cappedFirstLetter.toLatin1()[0];
```

UPDATE:

I would solve your problem in the following way:

```
QChar c1 = sub[0];
c1 = c1.toUpper();
sub.replace(0, 1, c1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the member function [`toLatin1`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toLatin1), which returns a `QByteArray`. You then assign this `QByteArray` object to a `char` variable (not `char*`, just `char`).